# cumulative frequency column but resetting under a condition

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (on Python) with columns that contains the time and the number of products associated to an specific order.

I created a column that splits the time in intervals of 30 minutes (block of time) and then I counted the number of products on that specific Block of Time (using groupby).

Now I would like to add a cummulative frequency that restarts on every single block.

[image]

On this example, my new columns should be [2,3,3,5,7,...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the cumsum for each group like this:

```py
df.groupby('Block of Time')['N Products'].cumsum()
```

Which yields the following result:

```
0    2
1    3
2    3
3    5
4    7
Name: N Products, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Cumulative Sum* for each *Block of Time* within dataframe can be achieved by [`GroupBy.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
         'N Products'       : [2, 1, 3, 5, 2],
         'Block of Time'    : ['12:30:00', '12:30:00', '13:30:00', '14:00:00', '14:00:00'],
         'Products on Block': [3, 3, 3, 7, 7],

})

print(df)
#   N Products    Block of Time      Products on Block
#0           2      12:30:00                  3
#1           1      12:30:00                  3
#2           3      13:30:00                  3
#3           5      14:00:00                  7
#4           2      14:00:00                  7
```

Output:

```
df['Cumulative Products'] = df.groupby('Block of Time')['N Products'].cumsum()
print(df)
#    N Products   Block of Time      Products on Block   Cumulative Products
#0         2        12:30:00                  3                    2
#1         1        12:30:00                  3                    3
#2         3        13:30:00                  3                    3
#3         5        14:00:00                  7                    5
#4         2        14:00:00                  7                    7
```

CDF Plot:

```
df['Cumulative Products'].hist(cumulative = True)
```

[image: img]